# spacebar to toggle radio inputs

Tags: html, radio-button, accessibility

I have a list of radio buttons and for accessibility purposes, I'm trying to make sure that pressing spacebar toggles the state of the radio button. However, it is not toggling when I'm pressing spacebar. Any help will be much appreciated. Is there anything wrong in my HTML code structure? This is my code:

```html
<ul class="filter-group__list filter-group__list--sort" tabindex="0"><li class="filter-item">
                  <label data-sort="" for="filter-featured" class="filter-item__content" tabindex="0">
                    <input tabindex="0" type="radio" name="sort_by" data-sort-item-input="" checked="" value="Featured" data-value-escaped="Featured" id="filter-featured" class="filter-item__radio">

                    <div class="filter-item__content-inner">
                      <span class="filter-item__label">Featured</span>
                    </div>
                  </label>
                </li><li class="filter-item">
                  <label data-sort="" for="filter-best-selling" class="filter-item__content" tabindex="0">
                    <input tabindex="0" type="radio" name="sort_by" data-sort-item-input="" value="Best selling" data-value-escaped="Best%20selling" id="filter-best-selling" class="filter-item__radio">

                    <div class="filter-item__content-inner">
                      <span class="filter-item__label">Best selling</span>
                    </div>
                  </label>
                </li><li class="filter-item">
                  <label data-sort="" for="filter-alphabetically-a-z" class="filter-item__content" tabindex="0">
                    <input tabindex="0" type="radio" name="sort_by" data-sort-item-input="" value="Alphabetically, A-Z" data-value-escaped="Alphabetically,%20A-Z" id="filter-alphabetically-a-z" class="filter-item__radio">

                    <div class="filter-item__content-inner">
                      <span class="filter-item__label">Alphabetically, A-Z</span>
                    </div>
                  </label>
                </li><li class="filter-item">
                  <label data-sort="" for="filter-alphabetically-z-a" class="filter-item__content" tabindex="0">
                    <input tabindex="0" type="radio" name="sort_by" data-sort-item-input="" value="Alphabetically, Z-A" data-value-escaped="Alphabetically,%20Z-A" id="filter-alphabetically-z-a" class="filter-item__radio">

                    <div class="filter-item__content-inner">
                      <span class="filter-item__label">Alphabetically, Z-A</span>
                    </div>
                  </label>
                </li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard behaviour for Radio control, you might want to change it to Checkbox in order to achieve behaviour you want.

Otherwise, you have to write some Javascript in order to get what you described.

```html
<ul class="filter-group__list filter-group__list--sort" tabindex="0"><li class="filter-item">
                  <label data-sort="" for="filter-featured" class="filter-item__content" tabindex="0">
                    <input tabindex="0" type="checkbox" name="sort_by" data-sort-item-input="" checked="" value="Featured" data-value-escaped="Featured" id="filter-featured" class="filter-item__radio">

                    <div class="filter-item__content-inner">
                      <span class="filter-item__label">Featured</span>
                    </div>
                  </label>
                </li><li class="filter-item">
                  <label data-sort="" for="filter-best-selling" class="filter-item__content" tabindex="0">
                    <input tabindex="0" type="checkbox" name="sort_by" data-sort-item-input="" value="Best selling" data-value-escaped="Best%20selling" id="filter-best-selling" class="filter-item__radio">

                    <div class="filter-item__content-inner">
                      <span class="filter-item__label">Best selling</span>
                    </div>
                  </label>
                </li><li class="filter-item">
                  <label data-sort="" for="filter-alphabetically-a-z" class="filter-item__content" tabindex="0">
                    <input tabindex="0" type="checkbox" name="sort_by" data-sort-item-input="" value="Alphabetically, A-Z" data-value-escaped="Alphabetically,%20A-Z" id="filter-alphabetically-a-z" class="filter-item__radio">

                    <div class="filter-item__content-inner">
                      <span class="filter-item__label">Alphabetically, A-Z</span>
                    </div>
                  </label>
                </li><li class="filter-item">
                  <label data-sort="" for="filter-alphabetically-z-a" class="filter-item__content" tabindex="0">
                    <input tabindex="0" type="checkbox" name="sort_by" data-sort-item-input="" value="Alphabetically, Z-A" data-value-escaped="Alphabetically,%20Z-A" id="filter-alphabetically-z-a" class="filter-item__radio">

                    <div class="filter-item__content-inner">
                      <span class="filter-item__label">Alphabetically, Z-A</span>
                    </div>
                  </label>
                </li></ul>
```